# Node Express sending get request on static file in windows with backslash in path

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

I see that windows uses \ for path. When same request is issued to backend api it works fine but when issued from axios in frontend, it converts \ to %5C.

what happens differently when request is sent from postman and axios.

At front end:

> http://myIp:5000/public\images\ImageName.jpeg

At the back end server:

> GET /public%5Cimages%5CImageName.jpeg 401

[image: image showing error]

Comment: dont use \'s instead use / :/

Comment: URLs use `/` as path delimiters and that is independent of back-end platforms.  URLs are standard.  If, once you are on a Windows server, you are trying to convert a URL to a file path to access via Windows APIs, then you will have to convert forward slashes to backslashes in order to use them with the Windows file system.  When using nodejs `fs` APIs, you can use either forward or backslashes on Windows and the nodejs `fs` library handles the forward slashes for you.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone iam pretty new to js. i use file.path while uploading the photo which defaults to '\', i guess, is there a way i can change to '/' or a simple string replace will do?

Comment: @BharatKothari Yes, simply replace all \ with `/`. This isn't the best solution in the long-term, but it will surely fix the problem for now. (Sorry about the format issues, backslashes and markdown don't play well together)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I correctly understand your question, but may lend you something that helps locate the problem.

In the http uri, the only separator is /. So to GET a static file at `static\icon.jpg`, you fire a GET request to `static/icon.jpg`

To explain the `%5C` nonsense, I recommend to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding. To put it simple, only few characters are allowed to exist in the uri. To expand the charset used in uri, people invented a code scheme. In this scheme, `\` is translated to `%5C`

Answer (score 0):

Postman has built-in fault tolerance which converts \ to / automatically

For Example:
When I intentionally typed wrong in URL
[image: Image with wrong request URL]

To Check what Postman send to your back-end: click code button (present under save button)

[image: Image with Code Button Location]

you can see the corrected URL
[image: Image with Corrected URL by Postman]

Axios is a REST Client which doesn't do anything to correct URL but convert it and make a REST Call.

The main differences is that Postman Corrects the URL before making a REST Call but Axios doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the answers above.This worked for me. Simply replace %5C with /

```
filepath = filepath.replace(/%5C/g, "/");
```